# need to wrap h3 and div in wrapper div with jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="accordion">
  <h3>My title</h3>
  <div>My content</div>
  <h3>My title</h3>
  <div>My content</div>
  <h3>My title</h3>
  <div>My content</div>
</div>
```

What I need to do via jQuery is wrap each of the h3's and div's in another div class="myDiv", so the final output would look like:

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="myDiv">
    <h3>My title</h3>
    <div>My content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="myDiv">
    <h3>My title</h3>
    <div>My content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="myDiv">
    <h3>My title</h3>
    <div>My content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How would I do this with jquery?

Comment: Swear this was asked yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
$('.accordion h3').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('h3').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="myDiv"/>');
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qtNSS/)

See the API:

- [`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil)
- [`andSelf`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf)
- [`wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll)

Comment: Perfect! That did the trick! Thanks for your help lonesomeday!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("h3").each(function(){
   $(this).next("div").andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='myDiv'></div>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BSQpf/